# The difference between the following two neo4j cypher statements ？

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

**Query**

```
match (u:SomePersonBean{sex:"m"}) return u  limit 10
```

this query will return 10 result! But...

```
start u=node:SomePersonBean(sex="m") return u  limit 10
```

this query return 0 result! **WHY?**

What the difference between the following two neo4j cypher querys ?

Which uses the index?

Which uses the label-base index?

Which uses the Legacy index?

Comment: I believe both use the label index.  The one that uses START uses the legacy index.  If you want to know the detailed differences, ask the neo4j-shell for the query plan.   Type "profile" before the query, i.e. profile match (u:SomePersonBean{sex:"m"}) return u  limit 10 and the shell will explain how it executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query uses the legacy index, that you have to populate manually.

The first one is the way to go.

See: for [schema index](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-schema.html) and for [legacy index](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html).